# How can I get the current database in a Java class

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I'm trying to get the current database from a servlet that uses a Java Class but I'm not able to do it **without extending AgentBase** in that Class. I mean, I want to know the current database of a Java Class, is that possible?

I'm using the servlet for authentication, and then I want to save some login information into a document, but for that I need the current database. I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40485328/ls2j-get-session-from-ls-agent-into-java-class) before but I'm not 100% sure wether this is possible or not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It seems you've got things upside down and backwards.  From the java language perspective, there is never any such thing as a "current database" tightly associated with (i.e. as a ***property of***) a given java class.

Java classes are just software, just software is intended to be just deployed to some runtime environment, where "which database to connect to" is part of the [information contained/configured in that] runtime environment.  That's intentional and by design, because otherwise it would even be impossible to first test anything in a test environment before deploying it ***as tested*** to a production environment.

So by definition, "the current database" (whatever that means) can only be obtained from looking at the runtime configuration (whatever that looks like and wherever that's to be found).

Comment: I agree with your answer. I know what you say, it's just that I haven't explained it properly. Anyway, what I need is to get the Database, but I'm unable to get the Lotus Session object and without a session I think I can't get the database

Answer (score 0):

The Session class has an AgentContext property which contains a getCurrentDatabase().
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_CURRENTDATABASE_PROPERTY_JAVA.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't use AgentBase because it's not an agent, is just a Java Class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AgentBase has a getSession() method and Session has a  getCurrentDatabase() method.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/reference/r_domino_Session_getCurrentDatabase.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can't use AgentBase because it's not an agent, is just a Java Class. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Hi  Maybe this link helps https://flylib.com/books/en/1.480.1/writing_java_servlets.html or http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=2307
Or have look a the Notes Designer Help: NotesThread.sinitThread()

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to invoke the Domino classes. Outside AgentBase, getting the current session involves the instantiation of a NotesFactory.

Check the examples at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_EXAMPLES_COMPILING_AND_RUNNING_JAVA.html ; one of those ways of invocation should be appropiate for your use case.